# when to use yet/still with 'though' in a sentence

Tags: sentence-construction

I recently came across this sentence:

> Though, he is good yet he is mischievous

Should we use 'yet'or 'still' here and why?

Comment: Either "yet" or "still" is fine to use in this sentence, although "yet" does sound a little bit archaic, like something written in the past century.  But it might be a common phrasing in another dialect.

Comment: I would write it: Though he is good, he is still mischievous. The comma also made the sentence difficult to read.

Comment: Or simply "He is good *though* he is mischievous"

Answer (score 1):

In your example

> yet

is used to contrast two opposing characteristics in the pattern

> though **A** yet **B** *which contradicts A*
>
> Though he is good **yet** he is mischievous.
>   *although he is good he is still mischievous*

You would not use "still" in place of "yet" but "but still"

> He is good *but still* he is mischievous.

possibly the most famous use of this "yet" structure is *John 11:25 KJV*

> Jesus said unto her, I am the resurrection, and the life: he that believeth in me,
>   [*though he were dead, yet shall he live*](https://www.kingjamesbibleonline.org/John-11-25/).